# How to send null value to a stored procedure?

Tags: sql, asp.net, .net, sql-server, vb.net

My stored procedure looks like this:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[insertCompList_Employee]
   @Course_ID int, 
   @Employee_ID int, 
   @Project_ID int = NULL, 
   @LastUpdateDate datetime = NULL,  
   @LastUpdateBy int = NULL                     
AS 
BEGIN 
   SET NOCOUNT ON 

   INSERT INTO db_Competency_List(Course_ID, Employee_ID, Project_ID, LastUpdateDate, LastUpdateBy) 
   VALUES (@Course_ID, @Employee_ID, @Project_ID, @LastUpdateDate, @LastUpdateBy) 
END
```

My asp.net vb code behind as follows:

```
    dc2.insertCompList_Employee(
    rdl_CompList_Course.SelectedValue, 
    RadListBox_CompList_Select.Items(i).Value.ToString, 
    "0",
    DateTime.Now, 
    HttpContext.Current.Session("UserID")
)
```

I want to insert a `null` value for `Project_ID` instead of `0`

I had tried `NULL`, `'NULL'` but it returns error.

Comment: Have you tried passing null without quotes or passing DBNull.Value

Comment: yes, i had tried DBNull.Value , null, "". but it doesn't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally i got the solution...

i use Nullable Type for the project_id.
Declare it as follow:

```
Dim pid As System.Nullable(Of Integer)
```

and then code behind to insert data via store procedure

```
dc2.insertCompList_Employee(
rdl_CompList_Course.SelectedValue, 
RadListBox_CompList_Select.Items(i).Value.ToString, 
pid, 
DateTime.Now, 
HttpContext.Current.Session("UserID"))
```

Answer (score 9):

Use the built in value: `DBNull.Value`

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.dbnull.value.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-1

Answer (score 1):

I don't see the code where you are converting the values into parameters, but just don't add the parameter to the parameter collection if it should be null. It works fine whenever there is a default in the stored proc, in your case null.

```
if projectid <> 0 then
   cmd.addwithvalue("@ProjectId",projectid)
end if
```